# approximating an integral/hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, approximation-theory, hypergeometric-function

I am looking to approximate the following integral for small $z$:

$\int_0^{\infty}dy \frac{1}{z} e^{-y/z} \frac{w e^{-y}}{s + w e^{-y}}$ .

The integral can be solved in general to be a hypergeometric function:

$ \frac{w}{s (z + 1)}\times_2F_1(1, 1 + 1/z; 2 + 1/z; -w/s)$

so expanding that in small $z$ is also an idea (though Mathematica refuses to do so).
By numerical trial and error, I have found that the expression

$\frac{w (1-z)}{s + w (1-z)}$

is a decent approximation and I have been trying to prove that to be the case.
My attempts have been along the lines that when $z$ is small, $e^{-y/z}$ should decay very rapidly. In the limit of $z$ being zero, I can use a Delta function and get a result that I expect. However adding in a width of $z$ puts me at an impasse.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Just expand $we^{-y}/(s+we^{-y})$ into Taylor series in $y$ around the point $y=0$. Integrating $k$th term of this series will give you $z^k$ times some coefficient independent of $z$.

Comment: That would work but it won't get into the particular form I would like $w(1-z)/(s+w(1-z))$. The reason I desire this form is that I will eventually do an inverse Laplace transform and I get an exponential (at least at short times)

Comment: Then you are asking about something different from small $z$ asymptotics. Your expression reproduces $0$th and $1$st term of that asymptotics but already the $2$nd term is different. Obviously, by considering more and more complicated rational functions of $z$, one can reproduce more and more terms, but what are the additional conditions you put on these rational functions and where do they come from?

Comment: And by the way the expression $w/(s+w+sz)$ will have exactly the same merits.

Comment: I do not think you got the right approximation.

Comment: Try this one $-{\frac {w \left( sz-s-w \right) }{{s}^{2}+2\,sw+{w}^{2}}}.$

Comment: My main goal is to calculation the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1/s - I/s}{1 - (1 - \gamma^2) I}$ where $I$ is the integral I've originally stated. Putting both of your approximations for the integral yield okay agreement with the exact result but my 'guess' for $I$ still is much better up to about z = 0.75.

Comment: @BeauGeste: Note that, this approximation works fine as long as $z$ is in the neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: your approximation? yes, I realize that. I don't understand why my "approximation" works at much higher z than yours.

Answer (score 0):

If assuming that the result obtaining from the integral is correct, your question is how to approximate the given hypergeometric function with condition that $z$ is very small.

Applying the Euler's hypergeometric transformation (Mathworld - Wolframalpha, equation (32)) and series expansion (equation (7)) gives
\begin{align}
S &=\frac{w}{s(z+1)}\,{}_2F_1\left(1, 1+\frac{1}{z}; 2+\frac{1}{z};-\frac{w}{s} \right) \\
&=\frac{w}{s(z+1)}\left(1 + \frac{w}{s}\right)^{-1}\,{}_2F_1\left(1, 1; 2+\frac{1}{z}; \frac{w}{w+s}\right) \qquad (\text{Euler's transformation})\\
&= \frac{w}{(z+1)(w+s)}\, \left[1 + \frac{1\times 1}{1!(2 + 1/z)} \frac{w}{w+s} + \frac{1(1+1)1(1+1)}{2!(2+1/z)(2+1/z+1)}\left(\frac{w}{w+s}\right)^2 + \cdots\right]\\
&\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad(\text{series expansion})
\end{align}
Hence, if $z$ is small and $|w/(w+s)| < 1$, all of terms in the series expansion are very small, except the lowest order term. Hence, we can approximate the expression to
\begin{equation}
S \approx \frac{w}{(z+1)(w+s)}.
\end{equation}